# Excel VBA error handling not working for second error

Tags: vba, excel

In the below code `Errorhandler` correctly takes care of first error when I enter a workbook that is not open or any random string. But when I click on retry and again enter a random name I get "`Subscript out of Range`" error @ Workbooks(workbookname). Activate.

Can anyone help me why it is happening and how can I make it work.  I have tried a lot of things. But nothing is working. This code is part of a larger program.

```
Sub test()

Dim workbkname As String
On Error GoTo Errorhandler
Retry:

workbookname = InputBox("Enter workbook name:", _
                        "Name Enrty")
If StrPtr(workbookname) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Aborting Program")
    End
End If

Workbooks(workbookname).Activate
Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
Response = MsgBox("Workbook " & workbookname & " not found", vbRetryCancel)
If Response = 4 Then
    GoTo Retry

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Resume Retry` instead of `GoTo Retry`

Answer (score 14):

The issue here is that the VBA Error Handler does not clear the error once given a directive like `GoTo`.  As a result, the code thinks that it has encountered an error within your error handling routine and thus throws the error up the stack.

In order to clear the error, you must either call `Resume` with a place to resume (either `Resume` alone to run the erroneous code again, `Resume Next` to resume the line of code following the error, or `Resume` can be called followed by a label, as below:

```
Sub ErrTest
    On Error Goto ErrHndl
    For i = 0 to 5
        a = 1/i
nextiLabel:
    Next i

    Exit Sub
ErrHndl:
    Resume nextiLabel
End Sub
```

You can also use `Err.Clear()` to remove the error, but that is less recommended.

See here for more info: [Error Handling in Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)