# Why VBA error handling seems to be ignored here?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

The following statements (in a loop) end in an error when row 1 is empty.
I would have expected the error to be silently ignored and the next sheet to be processed.
How come the code stops when the `on error` is active ? I would expect it to ignore the error and continue processing after the `skip` label.

```
Sub listSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ar
    Dim a
    Set a = Application

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet1.Cells(3 + sh.Index, 1) = sh.Name
        On Error GoTo skip
        ar = sh.Range("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)  'code stops here if row 1 empty
        ar = a.Transpose(a.Transpose(ar))
        Sheet1.Cells(3 + sh.Index, 2) = Join(ar, "//")
        ar = Null
skip:
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Note: Error trapping is set to "Break on unhandled errors"

Comment: IF your `ar` is declared as Range you should use `Set ar = sh.Range("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ` . With `ar` declared as Variant - error is skipped. But the only error I've had - was error 91

Comment: It is declared as variant. code breaks when row 1 is empty, which would be normal if no `on error` was there. My question is why this `on error` does not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason lays in the fact you allready encountered an error. You however never cleared your error from the handler. A second error **won't** skip over that line again.

So to replicate this I had three worksheets, a blank row in the second and third. Your `On Error Goto` went through the second sheet but would return `Error 1004` on the third.

You might want to include an `Err.Clear`

```
On Error Resume Next
    ar = sh.Range("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)  'error 1004 on certain sheets
skip:
    Err.Clear
Next sh
```

---

***EDIT:*** Just found an alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930117/9758194)

---

And even then, maybe even drop the error handling completely and use something like:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
    ar = sh.Range("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
End If
```

Comment: Your suggested link solved the issue. Well done. The `error.clear` did not help. I finally used `on error Resume Next` and it works OK. It was a quick and dirty one shot code, but I was curious why these errors.

Comment: I haven't encountered this situation but it's very useful information

Comment: While `Err.Clear` does not work, the undocumented `On Error GoTo -1` could be used instead of `Resume`.

Answer (score 1):

A Resume statement is needed after an error occurs in which an error handler is enabled by the On Error statement.  As per VBA reference...

> If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler can't handle the error.

For additional information have a look at the following link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement